# Are there any good TouchID enabled banking apps

Tags: applications, touch-id, software-recommendation

Recently my online savings bank (CapitalOne 360, formerly ING Direct) forced me to change my credentials and now doesn't allow me to use a simple x-digit passcode to open my iPhone app.

I have to type in my strong web password every time - this is stupid; my iPhone is secured with a strong password/TouchID and I shouldn't have to type in my entire website password every time (for access through the web makes sense because anyone could try to access my account from anywhere and TouchID hasn't been introduced on Macs).  So either I have to make my web-password insecure enough so I can remember it every time, or I have to look it up .. every time I use the App!

Looked around and don't see many options - does anyone know of a good bank or credit union (US-based) that has a decent iOS app with TouchID functionality?

Note: thought about using 1password browser/safari plugin, but features like check-deposit don't exist on the mobile site, and require the app.

I am willing to move my account to whatever bank takes my iPhone banking seriously.

Comment: not an answer, just an agreement - my bank is the same, miserable 2-factor fumbling. I managed to get it to store my ID eventually, but still have to type my upper/lower case + numbers pw every damn time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of searching, decided to move my CapitalOne 360 to Discover Bank.  Only app I found, and they do everything I need so far (cash checks, bill pay, direct deposit).  App has TouchID :)

Still not clear why no other major financial institutions offer TouchID support - even USAA!

Answer (score 0):

I work for AgileBits, the company that makes 1Password.  While I don't know which banks have properly implemented Touch ID in their apps, I do have a suggestion that could help.  In iOS 8, Apple has allowed app extensions, and the 1Password app extension can be easily added to any app to allow easy sign-in (with no typing of those long and random passwords!)  We think that all apps - banks especially - should add this app extension.  If you agree that banks need 1Password, share [this link](https://agilebits.com/onepassword/devoutreach) with the developers and let them know!  Not only will it keep their users more secure, but it's easy for them to add.  :)

Cheers,

Megan O'Brien
Level 60 Support Sorceress at AgileBits
guides.agilebits.com

Comment: kudos to AgileBits for the 1Password extension into Safari. The touchID interface makes it extremely usable and functional.

Comment: Megan, my only issue with 1Password safari extension is even in Safari, the bank website often doesn't permit functionality like depositing checks through the mobile website (Safari or 1Browser).

Comment: Hi @r00fus, I'm sorry to hear that your bank's website isn't quite as flexible as their iOS app.  1Password makes it as easy as possible to copy and paste your password into iOS apps.  When you're viewing the item in the list view, just swipe right to copy the password.  It's not as perfect as having 1Password integrated into the bank's app ... but it's a good start!  

Cheers,

Megan O'Brien
Level 60 Support Sorceress at AgileBits
guides.agilebits.com

Answer (score -1):

Capital One, Chase and AmEx all allow TouchID sign-in.

Comment: Citibank also uses TouchID on their iPhone app for login, but it makes you type out the password when you want to transfer funds!